# Lego Star Wars ship identification, white and grey body, grey wings, dark red and yellow trim?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I really appreciate the help from you all earlier but I have one more LEGO set I need identified. I tried looking up by parts but couldn't find what I was looking for any suggestions from you all? I am even wondering if they are all from the same set.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is [8019-1: Republic Attack Shuttle](https://brickset.com/sets/8019-1/Republic-Attack-Shuttle)
[image]